# Dealing with parsing oids in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, client, protocols

I'm currently improving a library client for Postgresql, the library already has working communication protocol including DataRow and RowDescription.

The problem I'm facing right now is how to deal with values.
Returning plain string with array of integers for example is kind of pointless.

By my research I found that some other libraries (like for Python) either return is as unmodified string or convert primitive types **including** arrays.
What I mean by conversion is making Postgres DataRow raw data as Python-type value: Postgres integer is parsed as python number, Postgres booleans as python booleans, etc.

Should I make second query to get information column type and use its converters or should I leave it plain?

Comment: I don't get the question. How you return the data depends on what you want your library to do, which is determined by what you want it to provide or what the users of the library need.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Currently each column is converted using column `typeId` retrieved from DescribeRow. If the type is `16` which is boolean, I use `data == "t"` to convert into native boolean type. If it's a integer, I use a function to convert string to number. Etc. I want to handle all basic conversions.

Comment: Again as a comparison with Python pg library. if the query returns column of array type, you can index and iterate it as regular (native) python array.

Comment: So you already have the type OID (from DescribeRow). What are you missing? You already know the column type.

Comment: I'm missing all types. I can't just hardcode them because arrays of type `n` is created as new type. I had an idea to use `pg_type WHERE oid = *that type*` but there is lots of way to use data from pg_type. I saw in/out functions, delimiter, etc.

Comment: If I use my own solutions I need to account cases like array of text with escaped `}`, `,` or `"`. I thought there is easier way to handle any type.

Comment: I might be completely wrong. That's why I'm asking if I should convert values or leave them as raw strings. Note, I don't use libpg.

Comment: So your problem is that you get an OID and you don't know if that is an array type or not? Is your problem only about arrays?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226039/discussion-between-spar-and-laurenz-albe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could opt to get the array values in the internal format by setting the corresponding "result-column format code" in the Bind message to 1, but that is typically a bad choice, since the internal format varies from type to type and may even depend on the server's architecture.

So your best option is probably to parse the string representation of the array on the client side, including all the escape characters.

When it comes to finding the base type for an array type, there is no other option than querying `pg_type` like

```
SELECT typelem::regtype FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 1007;

 typelem 
---------
 integer
(1 row)
```

You could cache these values on the client side so that you don't have to query more than once per type and database session.